# Godot collision not working when object is moving away

Tags: collision, godot, gdscript

In my Jump and Run game you don't get damage when you're are colliding into the enemy from the back
but it's working when you're hitting it from it's front. I'm using a Kinematicbody2d for both the enemy and the player and an area2d for checking collision with the player. The enemy is slower than the player so if you are hitting it from the back you are slower too but you can see in the image that the colliders are not touching.

click to see the picture

[image: 1]

I tried messing around with the setting or making the colliders bigger but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use an Area2D to detect collision between two KinematicBodies. Use [get_slide_collision](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_kinematicbody2d.html#class-kinematicbody2d-method-get-slide-collision) instead:

```
for i in get_slide_count():
    var collision = get_slide_collision(i)
    print("Collided with: ", collision.collider.name)
```

Comment: I already tried to use get_slide_count but it has the same problem. I fixed it by using raycasts

Comment: Hmm. `get_slide_collision` should work without using raycasts. Are you moving the player with the `move_and_slide()` function?

Comment: yes I'am moving the player with this function , how I said it's working fine with raycasts and I wasn't using them before.